# Issue formulating django query between two tables

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've read at length about [django queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/).

But, despite my efforts to trying django [`forward` queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#forward) and [`backwards` queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) I just cannot get what I want.

i wrote a forward query:

```
ATUFS =  TSFH.objects.filter(FKToUser=request.user).values('sB','sE')
```

this returns:

```
{'sB': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 21, 18, 14, 2, 691185, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'sE': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 21, 18, 16, 2, 532731, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

But for this query I need also make a query that ensures `TSF.FKToT` a FK to another table `T` matches the local variable in my script `ed = request.GET.get('d', '')`. So essentially with this clause Im trying to achieve `T.dNm = ed` . Im just confused how to achieve this in my django forward query.

i wrote a backward query:
`ATFUS =  TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1').values('sB','sE
')`

This returns an error, that `sB`, and `sE` are not available to return the values for, because they're not in the `TSF` table.

In regular `SQL` Im simply trying to achieve

```
SELECT sB, sE 
FROM TSF, TSFH,T
where TSFH.id=TSF.FKToTSFH_id and T.id=tsf.FKToT_id;
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do via the `Django orm`?

Thanks

**UPDATED VIEW/TEMPLATE**

```
Completed=TSF.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user,FKToTSFH__sE__isnull=False).values('FKToTSFH__sB','FKToTSFH__sE')
return render(request, 'view.html', {
'C':Completed

 })

{% if C %}
{% for res in C %}
<li><span>{{ res.FKToTSFH.sB }}</span></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives an issue of blank output.

Any thoughts on how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this(as `sB` abd `sE` are in `TSFH` model, so you need to put `FKToTSFH__` before `sB` and `sE` like following):

```
TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1').values('FKToTSFH__sB','FKToTSFH__sE')

# with user

TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToTSFH__sB','FKToTSFH__sE')  # make sure user is authenticated
```

Bit more complicated way of acheiving this result is to annotate the value of `sE` and `sB` to the queryset, like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1').annotate(sB=F('TSFH__sB'), sE=F('FKToTSFH__sE')).values('sB','sE')
```

#### Usage

```
for item in TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1'):
     print(item.FKToTSFH.sB)
     print(item.FKToTSFH.sE)

for item in TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1').values('FKToTSFH__sB', 'FKToTSFH__sE'):
  print(item.get('FKToTSFH__sB'))
  print(item.get('FKToTSFH__sE'))

for (sB, sE) in TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1').values_list('FKToTSFH__sB', 'FKToTSFH__sE'):
  print(sB)
  print(sE)
```

#### Update 2:

You can use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) for checking null value exists or not:

```
# view
queryset = TSF.objects.filter(FKToTld__dNm='123.123.13.1', FKToTSFH__sB__isnull=False)
return ('template.html', context={'tsf': queryset})

# template

{% for i in tsf %}
    {{ i.FKToTSFH.sB }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks ruddra - how can i output the first code box?

Comment: Sorry, what do mean by output? do you mean how do you want to use the queryset?

Comment: yeah how do i loop through the queryset of code box #1?

Comment: @Jshee I have shared several examplex in the answer's update section. please have a look

Comment: Ruddra - very thorough thanks. i just have one more question: how would i ensure `sE` is not null in my `filter` ?

Comment: For the looping - how is this done in a django template

Comment: im included my updated view variable. im getting an issue with blank returned values to template.

Comment: Use `Completed=TSF.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user,FKToTSFH__sE__isnull=False)` only. ( without .values()). Just like in update 2